# Assigning a regex's test function fails

Tags: javascript, regex, function, assign, return-type

Why does `(/x/.test)("x")` work but attempting to give the `test` function an alternative name with `(t=/x/.test)("x")` or `t=/x/.test;t("x")` fails?

Firefox gives me a `TypeError: undefined is not a non-null object` while Chrome gives me an `Uncaught TypeError: Method RegExp.prototype.test called on incompatible receiver undefined`.

I realise that `(t=s=>/x/.test(s))("x")` and `t=s=>/x/.test(s);t("x")` work, but I'm trying to understand *why* the above doesn't.

Comment: I have had happened this to me before. It has something to do with native classes. Basically if you assign function from classes prototype to variable it will then lose its “this” value, thus breaking.

Comment: It's because you have the wrong `this`. you can use `Function.prototype.bind` `const t = function(expr) {return expr.test.bind(expr);}(/X/);`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Could you maybe flesh that out a bit and make it into an answer? Maybe explain the `this` bit further as my code doesn't contain any mention of `this`…

Answer (score -1):

I will try to explain again:    /x/.test or (/x/.test) this expression is executed as follows:

```
  /x/: a regular expression object is created. Similar to: new  RegExp (/x/).


 .test: The RegExp "test()" method is invoked. The string parameter of "test" method is mandatory. Not finding the parameterThen it returns error.
```

Why it works: function f (s) {}; g = f;
because you are assigning the function f to variable g. This assignment does not execute f. It is different from g = f() that in this case g will have the value returned by the function f.

Why it doesn't work: t = /x/.test because /x/ is creating the RegExp object or invoking its constructor. Then when returning this object it finds a call to test, therefore, it executes it but test does not have the required parameter therefore the error occurs. You can this: t=/x/; t.test("x"); First assign a regular expression object and then call test method.

I hope understand me now.

Comment: This does not answer my question. My question was a *Why?* question, not a *How can I make this work?* question.

Comment: t=/x/.test or (t=/x/.test)  you á forcing assign a "t"   the execution of regular expresion method test"  without parameter.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought function invocation required parenthesis. `f=s=>s+s;g=f;g(2)` correctly gives 4 while `f=s=>s+s;g=f()` makes `g` be `NaN` and `g(2)` give a `TypeError`.

Comment: But this is lambda function not assigment

Comment: I don't understand the difference, but maybe you can edit your answer to actually address my question by explaining this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your English correctly. By *Because you don't pasas a parameter then error result.*, do you mean *An error results because you don't pass a parameter.*? If so, then it still doesn't answer my question. I can see that an error results. Question is *why?*

Comment: Please don't rely on the order of comments. Either inline your code, or if you really need to post a code block, link to an external site.

Comment: Because "test" function of regex requires a parameter. Sorry for my english. You are treating a "test" as if it were a property and not a regex function.

Comment: Of course the test function needs a parameter, but so does `f=s=>s+s` and that doesn't prevent me from giving it an alternative name with `g=f` so why does `g=/x/.test` not work?

Comment: Because g=f you are assign a lambda function . "test" is not a lambda function.

Comment: I am not much of a JS programmer, but as far as I know, neither is `function f(s){return s+s}` a lambda function, but `g=f` still makes `g(2)` work.

Comment: In this case /x/ is a regular expresion function like /[^\s]/

Comment: If I understand correctly, `/x/` isn't a regular expression function, but rather just a regular expression, whereas `/x/.test` is a regular expression function.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp

Comment: That's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/RegExp for those that prefer English. I read all of that, but nowhere do I see anything that hints at why this would fail. Can you be more specific?